# Use SetFromElementLabels method in assembly

Tags: python, label, element, abaqus

I am trying to use the SetFromElementLabels method in an Abaqus Python script to create set of particular element. Works with PART as it should:

```
e = p.Set(edges=p.edges[0:1], name='edge')
elem = e.elements
n=len(elem)/5
p.SetFromElementLabels(name='my_el', elementLabels=(n, ))
```

But I cannot accomplish this with Assembly:

```
e_a=a.Set(edges=i.edges[0:1], name='a_edge')
elem_a = e_a.elements
n_a=len(elem_a)/5
a.SetFromElementLabels(name='me_ela', elementLabels=('Instance-1', n_a))
```

,
where:

- `p = mdb.models[name].parts[name]`;
- `a = mdb.models[name].rootAssembly`;
- `i = mdb.models[name].rootAssembly.instances[name]`;
- `'Instance-1'` is `name` + `-1` (if I've understood correctly ABAQUS Scripting Reference Manual)

What is wrong and how to fix it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean under 'you can't accomplish this'? What is the error? Set is not created or not expected elements are in the final set?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I wouldn't search for any object in Abaqus by its label if I didn't do the labeling manually. Any change in the geometry (e.g. partitioning) and your numbering could be changed and it is hardly traceable. From my experience, it is more reliable to use `FindAt` and `FindBy...` methods. Also `Set/Surface/etcByBoolean` can be handy.

Secondly, the set you create in Part module is accessible in the Assembly module:

```
my_set = a.sets['InstanceName.set_name']
```